Cauchy-Schwarz divergence between multivariate normal distributions
I am trying to derive the Cauchy-Schwarz divergence between two multivariate normal distributions using the derivation for the Cauchy-Schwarz divergence between mixtures of normal distributions from this paper: CLOSED-FORM CAUCHY-SCHWARZ PDF DIVERGENCE FOR
MIXTURE OF GAUSSIANS by CLOSED-FORM CAUCHY-SCHWARZ PDF DIVERGENCE FOR
MIXTURE OF GAUSSIANS
Kittipat Kampa, Erion Hasanbelliu and Jose C. Principe
Consider $p(x) = \mathcal{N}(x|\mu,\Lambda^{-1})=\frac{|\Lambda|^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^{\top}\Lambda(x-\mu)\Big)$ and $q(x) = \mathcal{N}(x|\nu,\Omega^{-1})=\frac{|\Omega|^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\nu)^{\top}\Omega(x-\nu)\Big)$.
Using the formula in the paper the Cauchy-Schwarz divergence can be simplified to:
\begin{align}
D_{CS}(p,q) &=-\log\Big(\mathcal{N}\big(\mu|\nu,(\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big)\Big) + \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{|\Lambda|^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Big) + \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{|\Omega|^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Big) \\
&= -\log\Bigg(\frac{\big|\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big|^{-1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Bigg) +\frac{1}{2}(\mu-\nu)^{\top}\big(\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big)^{-1}(\mu-\nu) + \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{|\Lambda|^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Big) + \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{|\Omega|^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\big|\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big|\Big) +\frac{1}{2}(\mu-\nu)^{\top}\big(\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big)^{-1}(\mu-\nu) + \frac{1}{4}\log\big(|\Lambda|\big) + \frac{1}{4}\log\big(|\Omega|\big)
\end{align}
However if I insert $p$ for $q$ I get:
\begin{align}
D_{CS}(p,p)= \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\big|2\Lambda^{-1}\big|\Big) + \frac{1}{2}\log\big(|\Lambda|\big) = \frac{D}{2}\log(2) \neq0
\end{align}
Where did I make a mistake?

I am too lazy to compute this exactly, but I would intuitively expect expressions with terms like $\sqrt{\frac{\Lambda+\Omega}{\Lambda \Omega}}$ instead of just $\sqrt{{\Lambda+\Omega}}$. You can make a quick verification with a zero mean monovariate distribution $$f(x) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-0.5ax^2}$$ and  $$g(x) = \frac{b}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-0.5bx^2}$$ then $$g(x)f(x) = \frac{ab}{2\pi} e^{-0.5 (a+b) x^2}$$ and it's integral looks to me as $\frac{ab}{a+b} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

The divergence is*
$$-2 \log \left( \int f(x)g(x) dx \right) +\log \left(  \int g(x)g(x) dx \right) +\log \left( \int f(x)f(x) dx \right) $$
These products of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are easy to compute as a product of Gaussian pdf's results in another Gaussian pdf (with some scaling factor). You can look them up in tables for conjugate distributions.
It seems like you probably missed a factor 2 in the variance for the expressions for $f(x)f(x)$ and $g(x)g(x)$.
I didn't verify this whether everything in your formula is correct, but intuitively those last terms should be analogous to the first term.
$$-\log\Bigg(\frac{\big|\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big|^{-1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Bigg) +\frac{1}{2}(\mu-\nu)^{\top}\big(\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big)^{-1}(\mu-\nu) + \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{|\Lambda^{-1} + \Lambda^{-1}|^{-1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Big) + \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{|\Omega^{-1} + \Omega^{-1}|^{-1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Big)$$
instead of
$$-\log\Bigg(\frac{\big|\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big|^{-1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Bigg) +\frac{1}{2}(\mu-\nu)^{\top}\big(\Lambda^{-1}+\Omega^{-1}\big)^{-1}(\mu-\nu) + \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{| \Lambda^{-1}|^{-1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Big) + \frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{|\Omega^{-1}|^{-1/2}}{(2\pi)^{D/2}}\Big)$$
*J. C. Principe, D. Xu, J. Fisher, S. Haykin, Information theoretic learning, Unsupervised adaptive filtering 1 (2000) 265–319. (online resource via research gate, several articles by Principe repeat the definition as well. In your reference the divergence differs by a factor two with these definitions as Whuber mentioned in the comments, but the principle is the same)

+1. But I believe the definition in the paper is half of yours.

@whuber I looked up the definition in some arxiv paper, I will add some decent reference.
